# i am getting result for first on change but not on second time...need to set original dropdown..how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On change of type and category, department should be change.it works for one time,but when i change category and type second time without refresh it does not works.i don't want to refresh page for second time or much more time.

```
<select id="CATEGORY_ID">
<option value="21">desc</option>
<option value="22">short</option>
<option value="23">medium</option>
<option value="24">long</option>
</select> 

<select class="bx-user-field-enum" name="UF_TYPE">
<option value="1">comp</option>
<option value="2">query</option>
<option value="3">fault</option>

</select> 

<select name=UF_DEPT>
<option value="21">Volvo</option>
<option value="22">Saab</option>
<option value="23">Mercedes</option>
<option value="24">Audi</option>
</select>
```

```
 $('#CATEGORY_ID,[name=UF_TYPE]').on('change', function() { 
    var id = $('#CATEGORY_ID').val();
    var select = $('.bx-user-field-enum').val();

if(id !=null && select !=null){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //dataType: 'json',
    url:"ajax_dept.php",
    data: {
      select: select, id: id
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        removeOptions(msg);

    }
  });
}
```

});

```
function removeOptions(msg) {
    var cars = document.getElementsByName("UF_DEPT")[0];
    var val = JSON.parse(msg); 

      for(var i=0; i<=cars.length; i++) {
        var isFound = false;
        for(var j=0;j<=i; j++) { 
          if(val[j] == cars[i].value) {
            isFound=true; 
              //cars[i].style.color="red";

              cars[i].style.display="block";
              break;
          }
        }
        if(!isFound) { 
            cars[i].style.display="none";


        }
          $('[name=UF_DEPT]').val(val[0]); 

      }  

    }
```

Comment: `cars` in the `removeOptions` function isn't an array or array-like object. So what do you want to iterate over? Also, I can't see an element with the ID `CATEGORY_ID`. Shouldn't that be `CATEGORY`? And what does `msg` look like?

Comment: I think you have wrong selector in your second code block, which is why ajax request is no firing for second time. It would be helpful if you create a fiddle for it...

Comment: @RajeshMaharjan - only problem is that..it set cars[] on first time. i want to reset to original dropdown on second time.. m getting ajax response on second time as wel..need to reset dropdown of department to original